# How I can get the checked values of drop down list into the cell of ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm developing an application using ag-grid in angular2 and want to get the checked values of drop-down list into the cell of ag-grid.

Comment: Welcome to SO please provide us your code, what your tried and what is the issue with it or why are you stuck.

Comment: Please post your tried code here so we can get to know how you are trying